# Getting multiple EXP. Shares

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

How do you get multiple **EXP. Shares** on *Pokemon LeafGreen/FireRed Versions* for Nintendo GameBoy Advance? No matter how hard I try, I can't figure it out. Is it even *possible*?? I feel the need to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the Serebii page](http://www.serebii.net/itemdex/exp.share.shtml), in FRLG, you get the Exp. Share from one of Oak's aides on Route 15, which means you can only get one.

Theoretically, you could have a friend trade you an extra one, or use two cartridges to trade yourself multiple, but you cannot get multiple in the same game.